# What do I risk by having deposited US Dollars in a Certificate of Deposit in a Greek bank?

Tags: deposits, greece

I have US$ in CD in a Greek bank.  What would happen if the bank folded, or Greece withdrew from the Euro/EU, or if there was a (even more) major financial crisis in Greece?

Comment: Are you having issues getting them out?

Comment: It's as safe as the bank is.

Comment: I see two people voted to close on this being too localized.  If they're referring to the geographic specificity, remember there are lots of USA-only questions.  If they're referring to the temporal specificity, remember that although it may be urgent at the moment, the question of "what happens if my bank folds" can always be asked.

Comment: @poolie but the question asks specifically in light of current conditions, not about the general question. If the question is changed, it can always be re-opened.

Comment: @sheegaon If that's your beef, you should edit the question appropriately. This question-attorney stuff is maddening.

Comment: Problem with that is that if it were edited to not be too localized, it would be a duplicate of [this](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/3115/4557).

Comment: @sheegaon It's similar to [that other question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/) is mostly about FDIC, which is I think also a valid country-specific question.

Comment: @duffbeer703 Good idea, I have attempted to do so.

Comment: If you are a US citizen or US resident, I hope for your sake you remembered to file the Foreign Bank Account Report, aka TD F 90-22.1 in the USA.  http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f90221.pdf

Comment: @Paul or for that matter even the spouse of a US Person :-/.  But perhaps George is just a Greek person with USD.

Answer (score 5):

Greek bank deposits are backed by the Greek government and by the European Central Bank. So in order to lose money under the insurance limits of 100k euros the ECB would need to fail in which case deposit insurance would be the least of most peoples worries.

On the other hand I have no idea how easy or hard it is to get to money from a failed bank in Greece. In the US FDIC insurance will usually have your money available in a couple of days. If there isn't a compelling reason to keep the money in a Greek bank I wouldn't do it.

Comment: "Wouldn't do it", meaning you would instead keep the money in USD in a bank outside of Greece?  I see your point.  Of course there is some hassle to opening a foreign bank account and accounting for it in tax returns, but perhaps George will think the risk-spreading makes it worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is that greece defaults on it's debts and the rest of the eurozone chose to punish it by kicking it out of the Eurozone and cutting off it's banks from ECB funds.

Since the greek government and banks are already in pretty dire straits this would leave greece with little choice but to forciblly convert deposits in those banks to a "new drachma". The exchange rate used for the forced conversions would almost certainly be unfavorable compared to market rates soon after the conversion. There would likely be capital controls to prevent people pulling their money out in the runup to the forced conversion. While I guess they could theoretically perform the forced conversion only on Euro deposits this seems politically unlikely to me.